# How to make a Wallpaper app for iPhone in XCode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, background-image, wallpaper

I'm trying to make a simple Wallpaper app for iPhone in XCode. Wherein i have a bunch of images in my app, user opens an image that they like, and there is a "Set as Background Image" button.  I have managed to make a library of images. How do i add the "Set as Background Image" funtionality?
Please help. I am grateful for any amount of help that i will get.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. Apple won't allow this functionality in third-party apps.

Your app runs on a sandbox environment, you can't change any property of the OS from your app.

As a work-around, you can give an option to save your image to photo-gallery, so user can choose the image from there and set it as wallpaper.

For Saving, you can use the following code:

```
- (void)saveImage:(UIImageView *)imageView
{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image, nil, nil, nil);
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
Oh really? Can i then just allow the user to save the image in the camera roll and from there, they can set it up as their wallpaper? Or is there any other way around?

Comment: @PratikP You can implement save to photo-gallery option.

Comment: Thank you Midhun for that piece of code. It is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do is give an option to save an image from your app to the Camera Roll, and have the user manually set that image as the background.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I was thinking on a similar track but i was wondering if I could minimize the number of steps involved in setting up a wallpaper.